# Bind CheckBox to enum value

Tags: c#, wpf

This seems like a very basic idea I just haven't been able to find an answer anywhere. I want to bind an enum type or class to a checkbox similar to how it can be done with a ComboBox. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public string Display {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the XAML bind to the class like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxMyCb" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMyClass}" DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

Then when an event happens I can get the value later like so:

```
int val = (int)comboBoxMyCb.SelectedValue;
```

Basically I want to do a similar thing but simpler. I am making a list of enum values and each value corresponds to a checkbox. My current set up is when I close the windows I check which checkboxes have been checked and add their corresponding enum value to the list. This makes for a lot of if statements because their can be upwards of 40 checkboxes. What I would like to do is bind each checkbox to an enum value in the XAML then set each of their onclick events to a function that looks something like this:

```
private void CheckBoxItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    MyEnum value = (MyEnum)cb.value;//or whatever
    if (cb.IsChecked == true)
    {
        EnumList.add(value)
    }
    else
    {
        EnumList.remove(value);
    }
}
```

I know some of the code is not optimal I just wrote this all as an example.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create each `CheckBox` in XAML, you can assign the enum type to the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netcore-3.1) property.

> Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.

I created an enum `MyEnum` with constants `MyEnumConstant1` and so on, replace it with your own.

```
<CheckBox Content="My enum constant 1" Tag="{x:Static local:MyEnum.MyEnumConstant1}" Checked="EnumCheckBoxChecked"/>
<CheckBox Content="My enum constant 2" Tag="{x:Static local:MyEnum.MyEnumConstant2}" Checked="EnumCheckBoxChecked"/>
<!-- ...the other 38 check boxes. -->
```

Using the `Checked` event, you can get the `Tag` and add the enum value to `EnumList` or remove it. Since I do not know exactly what your `EnumList` is, I leave it like it is in this sample code.

```
private void EnumCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
   var value= checkBox.Tag;

   if (checkBox.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
   {
      EnumList.add(value);
   }
   else
   {
      EnumList.remove(value);
   }
}
```

The [`IsChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_ToggleButton_IsChecked) property is a nullable `bool`. [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netcore-3.1) will return `false` if it is `null`.

You can also do this in an MVVM compliant way by using view models and binding to a command.

```
<CheckBox Content="My enum value 1" Command="{Binding CheckedCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static local:MyEnum.MyEnumValue1}"/>
```

Here, you do not need the `Tag` property, as you pass the enum constant as command parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a wrapper class to represent your Enum. For example, consider the sample enum

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
        [Description("Description 01")]
        Sample01,
        [Description("Description 02")]
        Sample02,
        [Description("Description 03")]
        Sample03
}
```

Now you could write a wrapper as

```
public class Wrapper
{
        public SampleEnum Value { get; set; }
        public string Description => GetEnumDescription(Value);
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        private string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
        {
            FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
                return attributes[0].Description;
            else
                return value.ToString();
        }
}
```

You could now create a collection in your view model as

```
public List<Wrapper> EnumCollection { get; set; }
```

Which could be initialized as

```
EnumCollection = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SampleEnum))
                .Cast<SampleEnum>()
                .Select(x => new Wrapper { Value = x, }).ToList();
```

This Collection can now be bound to your collection of Checkbox. For example,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EnumCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The IsSelected flag would help you trace if the particular enum is selected.